# Node.JS selenium send key enter

Tags: node.js, selenium

when i send a the reutn key in nodejs it gives a error?

```
driver.findElement(By.id('twofactorcode_entry')).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

All the sites tell me this is what i need to use? any help please

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: @PeterGrainger Its saying Keys is not defined

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using npm package Selenium Webdriver: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

The error Keys is not defined occurs because you haven't defined keys before using it.  You need to use the Enum Key (https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Key.html)

It is a constant on the driver module and exported as Key (note the singular form).  I've put the updated code below.

```js
const driver = require('selenium-webdriver')

driver.findElement(By.id('twofactorcode_entry')).sendKeys('webdriver', driver.Key.ENTER);
```

Extra tip: I've been using http://webdriver.io/ and it's a little easier to use than this library

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the other solutions didn't work for me.

Using Node.js, it seems you can just use `\n` for enter:

`await driver.findElement(By.id('my-field-id')).sendKeys('my-value\n');`

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
 
(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

Comment: This question is 3 years old, but thanks for the response! :D

Answer (score 1):

//Or alternatively define the Keys variable at the top..... e.g

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
Keys = webdriver.Key,
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;
```

Comment: variable expansion would be terser and more clear
const {Builder, By, Key, until, logging} = require('selenium-webdriver');

Answer (score 0):

You import Key from 'selenium-webdriver' but you are using

> Keys.ENTER

but it should be

> Key.ENTER