# How do I simulate 'Enter' Key button with Node .Js /Selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium

This is the code snippet I am using but it doesn't click

```
function ClickEnter(){
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('select2-result-label-3')).click();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.JS selenium send key enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428871/node-js-selenium-send-key-enter)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the 'Enter' key to an element like so:

`driver.findElement(By.id('select2-result-label-3')).sendKeys(driver.Key.ENTER);`

Taken from answer: [Node.JS selenium send key enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428871/node-js-selenium-send-key-enter)